# Remove rows with n smallest values in a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas' `nsmallest` in order to find n rows with smallest values in a specific column, and If I understand correctly it returns a data frame object;
How can I remove those rows from the data frame?
pandas' `drop` gets only rows indexes, not a data frame

Comment: Hello, we need a [minimal complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help. You can refer [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and create one in your question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop 3 smallest values of a `series` (or a specific column):

```
>>> sr
0    22  # <- drop
1    45  # <- drop
2    61
3    65
4    74
5    78
6    58
7    73
8    13  # <- drop
9    91
dtype: int64

>>> sr.nsmallest(3)
8    13
0    22
1    45
dtype: int64

>>> sr.drop(sr.nsmallest(3).index)
2    61
3    65
4    74
5    78
6    58
7    73
9    91
dtype: int64
```